# View Controller resize

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

How to change sizes of ViewController? I'm making simple app which uses deliberately two views, one for horizontal and one for vertical view. I was trying to resize it inspector-view but the fields are gray and unchangeable.

Comment: are you talking about changing orientations for one view or simply loading a new view when orientation changes?

Comment: Two independent views that will be like one "the same", but resized. But under the hood they are 2. one 320*460 and the second 460*320 and i want to change the second's size from 320*460 -> 460*320 and idk how.

Comment: didn't understand...if you want to change view size code i can give it..but view size is automatically changed when orientation changes...if the device is in horizontal..and then you set view to 320 x 480 then most of the elements will go offscreen...explain more

Comment: Ye, I know about this automatical resizing. But if you want to put hardly one view for vertical and the second one for horizontal, you have to resize it from 320*460 to 460*320 and put objects here. My question is, how to resize it in Interface Builder.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2qmhxmv&s=5 its grey so i can't do it

Comment: you are trying to change it in size inspevtor..although this won't be a solution but try this ..go to attributes inspector..and change orientation to horizontal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIViewControllers are not responsible for setting the size of their root view. It is expected that the parent of the view controller's view (either the window or some container view controller) will adjust the view's size to fill the window, fit above the tab bar, or otherwise be appropriately positioned. Interface Builder therefore doesn't allow you to set misleading frame values on that view.

To swap view based on orientation I suggest adding two sub-views to your root view and using one for each orientation. Even then the size you set for them in Interface Builder is somewhat misleading; you'll be able to set the sizes you want more importantly you should set their autoresizing properties such that they expand/shrink to fill their parent view. That way your layout won't break when the height of the status bar changes or you add a container view controller.